# Setting up a custom file name datatables export excelHtml5 with a select text

Tags: jquery, html, button, datatables, export

I'm wondering how to set a custom filename to export in datatables buttons excelHtml5 with a select, I did a function to pass the name but is not setting it ill post my js code. with the alert it is reflecting the changes but when i call the excel button in datatables is coming empty.

Here is the code:

```js
var reportName = '24 afterhours ';
$('#example').DataTable({
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
      {
         extend: 'excelHtml5',
         title: reportName
      },
      {
         extend: 'pdfHtml5',
         title: 'Data export'
      }
  ]
});

$('#campaing').change(function() {
   reportName += $(this).find(":selected").text() + ' report';
});
```

I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 7):

`title` is read *once* when the dataTable is initialised, and then the value is mapped into the internal `config` object. Therefore, if you want to change settings dynamically, you must change that internal `config` object, not try to change the readonly configuration settings.

So do it the other way around - create an event listener for the `<select>` *inside* the buttons `init()` callback itself. If you have a `<select>` with optional filenames like this

```html
<select id="filename">
    <option value="filenameA">filename A</option>
    <option value="filenameB">filename B</option>
    <option value="filenameC">filename C</option>
</select>
```

Then you can dynamically change the export `fileName` (== `title` + `extension`) by

```js
buttons : [
   {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'filenameA', //default filename
    init: function(dt, node, config) {
        $("#filename").on('change', function() {
            config.title = this.value;
        })
    }
},
```

You can change the other config properties from within the handler as well, for example you might want change `config.extension` to something else.

---

Here is a demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/y8d9zhfv/**
It is important to emphasize, that dataTables.buttons.js **1.3.0** or higher is required; this is also the case with the buttons.html5.js module. So if the above not work upgrade -> https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the filename config object to set it.
I have used this method for my export files and it works with earlier versions of dataTables.buttons.js as I am using it with v1.2.1, I am using it like so:

```
buttons: [
             {
                 extend: 'excel',
                 filename: function(){
                     return reportName;
                 }
             }
         ]
```

Where reportName is a variable I am setting when input options are changing.