# Change file export title in jquery datatables after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, datatables, export

I'm trying to dynamically change the export title for datatable file export. I found a solution including AngularJS which I'm not going to be able to use. Is there a solution just using jquery?

Here is where I initialize the buttons:

```
var oTable = $("#standards").DataTable({  
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            title: titleFinal,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: titleFinal,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        }
    ],
```

I have a function makeTitle that returns a string built from the input string. Here is where I try to change the title after clicking a link.

```
    $('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {

        titleFinal = makeTitle('XYZ Standards Due for Testing, ');

        oTable.buttons = [
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                title: titleFinal                                    
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: titleFinal
            }
        ];

        oTable
            .search('XYZ')
            .draw();
```

Comment: I think someone already answered your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953557/setting-up-a-custom-file-name-datatables-export-excelhtml5-with-a-select-text

Comment: That looks like it will work. Thanks for the pointer, sorry I missed it...